# Page long stretched on internet explorer 8/9 with Primefaces

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

My page is rendering correctly when using Google Chrome or Firefox. But when using IE8 or IE9, it gets stretched almost infinitely. It works well on IE10. This page is written in JSF. I am sorry this page is very long.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/CenterHomeTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="main-content">
            <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"
                closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="ajax-loader.gif" />
            </p:dialog>
            <div align="center">
                <h:form prependId="false" id="MigrateAccountForm">
                    <br />

                    <p:messages id="msg" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true"
                        showDetail="true" />
                    <p:tooltip />
                    <p:panel header="Enter following data for migating old account">
                        <h:panelGrid columnClasses="col1, col2, col3"
                            rowClasses="row1, row2" columns="3" id="grid">
                            <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Requester Email-id : " />
                            <p:inputText id="email" required="true"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.email}" title="Your Email-id"
                                validatorMessage="Invalid Email-Id : Email-Id must end with @oracle.com"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" size="25">
                                <f:validateRegex pattern=".+@oracle\.com$" />
                                <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
                                    onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />
                                <p:clientValidator event="blur" />
                                <f:ajax event="blur"
                                    render="manager-email email-msg cost-center group msg username"
                                    listener="#{accountCreationBean.fetchEmailInfo}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:message id="email-msg" for="email" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="account-type" value="Account Type : " />
                            <p:selectOneRadio required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" id="account-type"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.accountType}">
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="username nis-accounts"
                                    listener="#{accountCreationBean.changeAccountType}" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{accountCreationBean.accountTypes}" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                            <p:message for="account-type" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Existing Username : " />
                            <p:inputText id="username"
                                disabled="#{accountCreationBean.accountType == 'Individual'}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" size="25"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.username}"
                                title="Existing username.">
                                <p:clientValidator event="blur" />
                                <p:ajax global="false" event="blur" update="username-msg"
                                    listener="#{accountCreationBean.checkUserNameAvailability}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:message id="username-msg" for="username" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password : " />
                            <p:password id="password" match="confirm-password"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" size="25"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.password}"
                                title="Enter old password">
                                <p:clientValidator event="blur" />
                            </p:password>
                            <p:message for="password" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="confirm-password" value="Confirm Password : " />
                            <p:password id="confirm-password" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" size="25"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.confPassword}" />
                            <p:message for="confirm-password" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="manager-email" value="Manager's Email-id : " />
                            <h:outputText id="manager-email"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.managerEmail}"
                                title="Email-id of your approver." />
                            <p:message for="manager-email" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="nis-accounts"
                                value="Permissible NIS Accounts : " />
                            <p:inputText id="nis-accounts" required="true"
                                disabled="#{accountCreationBean.accountType == 'Individual'}"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" size="25"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.nisAccounts}"
                                title="NIS users to be linked with this account. Separate multiple NIS accounts with comma." />
                            <p:message for="nis-accounts" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="privilege" value="Privileges : "
                                title="Select only required privivledges." />
                            <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="privilege" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" label="Privileges"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.selectedPrivileges}">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{accountCreationBean.privileges.entrySet()}" var="c"
                                    itemLabel="#{c.value}" itemValue="#{c.key}" />
                            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                            <p:message for="privilege" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="stack" value="Stack : " />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="stack" value="#{accountCreationBean.stack}"
                                required="true">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{accountCreationBean.stacks.entrySet()}"
                                    var="c" itemLabel="#{c.value}" itemValue="#{c.key}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:message for="stack" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="product-id" value="Product ID : " />
                            <p:inputText id="product-id" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field" size="5"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.productId}">
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]+" />
                                <p:clientValidator event="blur" />
                                <p:ajax global="false" event="blur"
                                    listener="#{accountCreationBean.populateProductName}"
                                    update="product-name product-id-msg" />
                            </p:inputText>
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:outputText id="product-name"
                                    value=" #{accountCreationBean.productName}" />
                                <p:message id="product-id-msg" for="product-id" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <p:outputLabel for="group" value="Group : " />
                            <h:outputText id="group" value="#{accountCreationBean.group}" />
                            <p:message for="group" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="cost-center" value="Cost Center : " />
                            <h:outputText id="cost-center"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.costCenter}" />
                            <p:message for="cost-center" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="svp-evp" value="SVP/EVP Email-Id : " />
                            <p:inputText id="svp-evp" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field"
                                validatorMessage="Invalid Email-Id : Email-Id must end with @oracle.com"
                                size="25" value="#{accountCreationBean.svpEvp}">
                                <f:validateRegex pattern=".+@oracle\.com$" />
                                <p:clientValidator event="blur" />
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:message for="svp-evp" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="comments" value="Comments : " />
                            <p:inputTextarea id="comments" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Mandatory Field"
                                value="#{accountCreationBean.comments}" />
                            <p:message for="comments" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                    <br />
                    <p:commandButton resetValues="true" value="Submit"
                        update="MigrateAccountForm"
                        action="#{accountCreationBean.migrateOldAccount}" />
                    <p:separator />
                    <p:outputLabel style="color: red">
                        <p:commandButton disabled="true" icon="ui-icon-info" />
                        <b>Note : </b>For generic accounts a suffix '_grp' will be added to username, if not present, from version 3.0. Till then, current username will work.
                        </p:outputLabel>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The Template used in this page is :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

    <h:head>

        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-layout, .ui-layout-doc, .ui-layout-unit, .ui-layout-wrap, .ui-layout-bd, .ui-layout-hd{
                //border: none; 
                margin: 0;
            }

            .upper-left-menu {
                height: 50px;
            }

            .ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
                font-size: 95% !important;
            }

        </style>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div align="center">
            <table style="border:2; width:70%; border-collapse: collapse">
                <tr style="background: aliceblue;">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <ui:insert name="header">
                            <ui:include src="/includes/header.xhtml"/>
                        </ui:insert>
                    </td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><ui:include src="/tabs/tabs.xhtml"/></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div align="center">
                        <ui:insert name="main-content">
                            <div style="height: 200px">
                                <h4>This is code Signing SErver Home Page.</h4>
                            </div>
                        </ui:insert>
                        </div>
                    </td>                
                </tr>
                <tr style="background: aliceblue">
                    <td style="border-top-color: aliceblue; border-top-style:  groove; border-top-width: thin;" colspan="2"> 
                        <ui:insert name="footer">
                            <ui:include src="/includes/footer.xhtml"/>   
                        </ui:insert>
                    </td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Now the page is stretched long way for IE8 and 9.
[image]

Is there some tag, that is needed to be added or some css or component that is creating problem?

Comment: @Tiny then what should i use?

Comment: even using your plain vanilla html/css template, is giving me same stretched which is not usable. You can seee in the above image, the scrollbar at bottom, how long it is.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked some time ago but I had just faced a similar issue. I'm hoping someone can benefit from this. I'm using PF 5.2 and as your question suggests, the page gets stretched almost infinitely. In my case the page was stretched when toggling the select all checkbox in the p:selectCheckboxMenu. A table on my page had been populated through my JS function on toggle. What I found was that when the table is populated, a tbody element tag is added to the table tag. When the elements are removed, there's a leftover tbody tag. For some reason IE doesn't like this. In my function where I'm updating this table based on my selection from my p:selectCheckboxMenu, I added this piece of logic and the page now renders correctly.

```
//Remove tbody when there are no more elements. In IE this is causing a rendering issue.
        if(table.rows.length === 0){
            if(table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]){
                table.removeChild(table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]);
            }
        }
```